# Obtaining value of Textbox contained within DataList: Where did I go wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm attempting to set the parameter of an insert command equal to the value of a text box contained within a DataList control.@  The following is my attempt at finding the relevant control and retrieving its value.

```
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox Amt = (TextBox)DataList1.Items[0].FindControl("RadTextBox1"); 
    e.Command.Parameters["@Amount"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Amt.Text);
  }
```

The above code sample does not work but also does not return any syntax errors.  I suspect I did something wrong in trying to get the textbox value because the insert statement works fine if I set the @Amount parameter equal to some arbitrary value.  Can someone please show me my mistake and how to correct it?

//Additional code per comment

DataList:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"><ItemTemplate>

        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalProratedAmountDue") %>'>
        </telerik:RadTextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Insert Button:

```
public void RadButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps because you're looking for RadTextBox1 but the ID is RadTextBox2?

If Amt.Text returns a NULL, then Convert.ToDecimal(Amt.Text) will return a 0. But I'm not sure what you mean by "the above example does not work". You mean no records get inserted?

Comment: The problem is that no records get inserted.  Also, the reference to RadTextBox2 was a copy paste error.  The correct DataList code now appears above.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.  If I change TextBox to RadTextBox it works properly.  I'll accept your answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Well to start - your code references RadTextBox1 yet in your markup its RadTextBox2